# How to remove specify rows from a data.frame

Tags: r

I want to apply this function columnwise to a data.frame . Subsequently, all rows in which NA`s were generated should be deleted from the data.frame.

```
remove_outliers <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  qnt <- quantile(x, probs=c(.25, .75), na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  H <- 1.5 * IQR(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  y <- x
  y[x < (qnt[1] - H)] <- NA
  y[x > (qnt[2] + H)] <- NA
  #y <- y[!is.na(y)]
  y
}
```

Comment: Try `df2 <- sapply(df1, remove_outliers);na.omit(df2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find your outliers with IQR, you can apply your function with apply columnwise to replace outliers with NA.
With which() you find the indexpositions of the 'datavector' - that is your columns stacked - and with modulo you get your row numbers in which the NA was detected. to remove the unique values, you only need indexing dataframe[-c(),] on the rows.

```
X <- apply(X,  MARGIN = 2, FUN = remove_outliers)
na_rows <- unique(which(is.na(X)) %% dim(X)[1])
X <- X[-na_rows, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the na.omit and this function [complete.cases](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/complete.cases.html)

It might help you to check out the other functions available

`y <- y[complete.cases(y), ]`

Should do it

Comment: `complete.cases()` is a function, not a library. Also this is not a complete answer.

Comment: In my defense, this is a very simple question and if well searched he would find the answer because I've already seen it.

Comment: I agree, maybe just use a comment instead.

Comment: I can't comment, not enough reputation

Comment: You should wait to have enough for comment. Also note that this: "You have the na.omit in this function complete.cases", it's not clear. You're talking about two different functions. `na.omit` and `complete.cases`.